# Is it possible to copy aws s3 folder with different name with aws sdk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, amazon-s3, copy, aws-php-sdk

I want copy one s3 folder with some different name  using php aws sdk. Is there a way to do this. I have not got any code to copy folder rather I only got for individual files.

Answer (score 1):

Using CLI, When passed with the parameter --recursive, the following cp command recursively copies all files under a specified directory to a specified bucket and prefix while excluding some files by using an --exclude parameter

```
aws s3 cp myDir s3://mybucket/ --recursive
```

Please look for the same in PHP SDK

Comment: I know about CLI but in php aws sdk I am not able to do this.

Comment: `cp --recursive` command uses a mix of list and copying aws s3 apis underneath it, as implemented [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/blob/09e9739b86fdb5c49c2d56528522e0077d57dbb1/awscli/customizations/s3/subcommands.py#L549).

Comment: @HonnavarDeepak - Did try using "Amazon S3 Stream Wrapper"? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/guide/feature-s3-stream-wrapper.html

Answer (score 0):

I am not an PHP developer, but considering the APIs that I use, you would [list all files](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/v2-RESTBucketGET.html) and use the [copy object](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectCOPY.html), as described at the PHP SDK documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-s3-2006-03-01.html#listobjects) and [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-s3-2006-03-01.html#copyobject).

For listing, you would use the `Prefix` parameter to set and list inside the folder you want.

For copying, the parameters that you need to look are `ContentSource` and `Key`.
`ContentSource` is "the name of the source bucket and key name of the source object, separated by a slash (/)". That object can be the folder you are copying. The `Key` parameter is the name name of the resulting object that you want.

With both you can do list everything and copy properly. There is more parameters that can be useful for you like `Delimiter` on list buckets for better filtering.

If you can use the [AWS CLI](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/) directly, there is 2 options to do that. One is using the [`s3 sync`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html) command or the [`s3 cp`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html). With them you can copy directly using the folder names that you want, from bucket to bucket, local to bucket, bucket to local. Using `cp` command, use `--recursive` option to loop through specified directory or prefix.